# Entity Framework Unique Validation on Local and Database

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Currently I am trying to handle unique validation for entities as part of my ValidateEntity method on my DbContext. The problem I am trying to solve is when adding multiple entities at the same time detecting the unique constraint errors before it hits the database. An example is the case when adding entity A and B making sure that A and B don't have the same name. Currently I have the unique indexes applied so at the very least the database will handle it, and I have the following code that can cover when A is already in the database:

```
if (this.Components.Any(x => x.Id != item.Id && x.Name == item.Name))
{
    result.ValidationErrors.Add(new DbValidationError("Name", "There already exists another component with that name."));
}
```

Is there anything simpler than doing the following then?

```
Expression<Func<Component, bool>> predicate = x => x.Name == item.Name;

if (this.Components.Where(x => x.Id != item.Id).Any(predicate) || this.Components.Local.Where(x => x != item).Any(predicate.Compile()))
{
    result.ValidationErrors.Add(new DbValidationError("Name", "There already exists another component with that name."));
}
```

**Edit**

The case when the "unique key" is made up of a foreign key is a more complex situation. When going against the database you need to use the foreign key field though when going against the local cache you can't always say when `ReferenceId == ReferenceId` due to them both being zero if the reference entities were also just added. Would the correct way of checking the local cache be the following or would I need to eager load the reference since during validation lazy loading is turned off?

```
this.Components.Local.Any(x => x != item && x.Name == item.Name && x.ReferenceId == item.ReferenceId && x.Reference == item.Reference)
```

Comment: Looks OK to me. I'd only check the Local collection first, may save a db roundtrip.

Comment: The pre-edit example worked for the simple case of when the unique index/key was made up of non-foreign key columns but ran into issues when there was a foreign key in the search due to it not being set to non-zero until after save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my problem and limit reuse I added the following extensions to help with unique validation.

```
public static bool UniqueCheck<TSource>(this DbSet<TSource> set, TSource item, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> uniquePredicate) where TSource : class, IAuditEntity
{

    var function = uniquePredicate.Compile();

    var localContains = set.Local.Where(x => x != item).Any(function);
    if (localContains) return localContains;

    var remoteContains = set.Where(x => x.Id != item.Id).Any(uniquePredicate);

    return remoteContains;
}

public static bool UniqueCheckWithReference<TSource>(this DbSet<TSource> set, TSource item, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> uniquePredicate, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> referenceUniquePredicate) where TSource : class, IAuditEntity
{
    var localContains = set.Local.Where(x => x != item).Where(uniquePredicate.Compile()).Where(referenceUniquePredicate.Compile()).Any();
    if (localContains) return localContains;

    var remoteContains = set.Where(x => x.Id != item.Id).Where(uniquePredicate);

    return false;
}
```

The second function deals with the case of the unique key being made of of foreign key references.